# Change size text of Label in xaml, c# with a button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm new in a Xamarin development. I hope that you can resolve my problem in a simple mode.

I have a page.xaml with a label and with two buttons: button1 "+" and button2 "-".

I want that if I click the button1, the size font of the label text will become bigger. If I will click button2, the size font of the label text will become smaller. How can I achieve this?

Page1.xaml

```xml
<StackLayout HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="Black">
    <label text="example text" fontsize="20"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Clicked="Button_Clicked1" Text="+"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Clicked="Button_Clicked2" Text="-"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```cs
private void Button_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `x:Name` attribut to your label:

```xml
<StackLayout HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Label x:Name="label" text="example text" fontsize="20"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Clicked="Button_Clicked1" Text="+"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Clicked="Button_Clicked2" Text="-"/>
</StackLayout>
```

2. In code behind do the following

Page1.xaml.cs

```cs
private void Button_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.FontSize += 1;
}

private void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.FontSize -= 1;
}
```

I've checked and it works ;-)

Comment: can you +1 this answer then?

Comment: sure, but if i want to do it to all the label that i have in my page? if i have 20 label how i can change the fontsize to all this label?

Comment: as I've said in another comment: please ask another question on SO. It's hard to answer in a comment. For now, I can give you small hint: fontsize is bindable. If you don't know what bindables are, please read about bindable properties and about MVVM pattern. You can bind font size to some property and later increasing/decreasing that property will update the UI. Having that said you should have enough to start. If that does not help, please ask another question on SO. Good luck!